# Difference between "etwas zu trinken" and "etwas trinken"

Tags: difference, modal-verb

I would like to know the difference between the following two sentences:

> Ich möchte etwas zu trinken.
>
> Ich möchte etwas trinken.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe the difference is best explained by translating both sentences:

> Ich möchte etwas zu trinken: 
>   I would like *something to drink.*

The person is stating, that he/she desires the *object* (or rather: liquid) he/she wants to drink. Note that you could also use *etwas zum Trinken*.

> Ich möchte etwas trinken:
>   I would like *to drink something.*

This case emphasises the action of *drinking*.

Usually, both versions can be used interchangeably, although I would say the first one is more common, especially in situations discussing the act of buying food/drink (the object), like in a restaurant.
In contrast, *Ich möchte etwas trinken* would be a way to tell that you are generally thirsty, and need to drink something (in this case the *drinking* is more important).